# How can I create RRD files in Perl?

Tags: perl, rrdtool, rrd

I have a separate application printing logs in every 10 seconds. I need to create RRD files from the log files. I need some Perl code to read the log files and create the RRD only without the graphs.

I have also gone through the available Perl module in CPAN, i.e. [RRD::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RRD::Simple) and RRD::Simple::Examples, but I still need help.

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? This is not a website where people will give you code, it is a website where people will help you with programming problems.

Comment: @Chris: I need help to start coding in perl to create rrd's. If you can suggest me any sample code to start with.

Comment: Well, the Synopsis section of the module shows you what to do. What happened when you tried those examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with [RRD::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RRD-Simple/). There's some example code in the documentation. Since you don't need to create a graph, simply skip that section of the example.

Some of the examples read a single sample of data, call the `update` function once, and then exit. Those scripts are meant to be run periodically to collect data in real time. The example that's probably more pertinent to your needs is [ApacheAccessLogActivity.pl](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/NICOLAW/RRD-Simple-1.44/examples/ApacheAccessLogActivity.pl), which reads an Apache log file, parses each line with a regular expression, does a bit of analysis to figure out what it just read, and then calls `update`, all in a loop. Note that that example uses the standalone functions rather than the object-oriented versions.

If you've already read the documentation for that module and need more information about how to use it, or if you've tried it and found that it has shortcomings that prevent you from using it, then please be more specific about what you need to do.

[RRDTool::OO](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RRDTool-OO/) also looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend RRDTool::OO.
Exerpt from the perldoc:

$rrd->create( ... )
           Creates a new round robin database (RRD). A RRD consists of one or
           more data sources and one or more archives:

```
           $rrd->create(
                step        => 60,
                data_source => { name      => "mydatasource",
                                 type      => "GAUGE" },
                archive     => { rows      => 5 });
```